# Neo4j/Cypher _LOCK_ good or bad?

Tags: neo4j, transactions, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

Suppose you have `(:User)` node which has `SubscribersCount` property.

Each time someone subscribes/unsubscribes from user `User.SubscribersCount` should be updated accordingly. `[:SUBSCRIBED]` relation will be create/deleted on such action as well.

In this case in order to update counter you can:

- calculate all incoming `[:SUBSCRIBED]` relationships in realtime
- acquire write lock to `(:User)` node and increment/decrement counter

First approach will degrade as user subscribers number grows.

What about second approach? What downsides can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATED (thrice)]

To start the discussion, here are example Cypher queries for your 2 options.

1. Calculate the relationship count as needed (without a `SubscribersCount` property):

   (a) ADD a relationship:

   ```
       MATCH (u:User {id:1234}), (v:User {id: 5678})
       CREATE (u)<-[:SUBSCRIBED]-(v);
   ```

   (b) GET the count using `SIZE` [according to @NicoleWhite, this *should* execute in constant time as long as the pattern used does not specify a label for the subscriber's node and `u` is already cached]:

   ```
       MATCH (u:User {id:1234})
       RETURN SIZE((u)<-[:SUBSCRIBED]-());
   ```

   (c) **(deprecated)** GET the count using `COUNT` [neo4j has to iterate through all relationships (of all types) for that user]:

   ```
       MATCH (u:User {id:1234})
       RETURN COUNT((u)<-[:SUBSCRIBED]-());
   ```
2. Maintain a `SubscribersCount` property on each `User`:

   (a) ADD a relationship [same as above, but with an additional `SET`]:

   ```
       MATCH (u:User {id:1234}), (v:User {id: 5678})
       CREATE (u)<-[:SUBSCRIBED]-(v)
       SET u.SubscribersCount = u.SubscribersCount + 1;
   ```

   (b) GET the count [constant time complexity]:

   ```
       MATCH (u:User {id:1234})
       RETURN u.SubscribersCount;
   ```

### Conclusion

Assuming that it is true that option 1b does perform in constant time once the `u` node is cached, then you should probably always use option 1a to add a `SUBSCRIBED` relationship and 1b to get the count of such relationships. Maintaining your own count would probably be slower.

However, as @drgraduss reminds us, if you need to filter the relationship by properties or use labels, then option 1b will not run in constant time.

- Some examples:

  ```
  SIZE(()-[:SUBSCRIBED {prop:val}]->(u))
  SIZE((:label)-[:SUBSCRIBED]->(u))
  ```
- In this case, option 2 *may* be better, since 2a and 2b run in constant time.

Comment: I mentioned this as first option, calculating on the fly. if you need to query User regularly and return number of subscriptions, query performance will degrade as number of subscriptions grow.

Comment: Your question started out by saying that `User` has a `SubscribersCount` property. So I was interpreting your ambiguous first option as saying you wanted to update that property as each relationship was added/removed.

Comment: there will be no performance drawback by counting the number of relationships, even for millions, use size() instead of count() as size will trigger java's getDegree()

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen: I just rewrote my answer based on some older documentation about how relationships are stored, which led me to conclude that counting the number of relationships for a node is dependent on the number of relationships. Is there some better documentation that shows this is not true? Thanks.

Comment: I found [this blog](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/07/23/node-degrees-neo4j.html) from 2014 that indicates getDegree() runs in constant time in version 2.1, but only when running in the heap cache. However, I know that in 2.3 neo4j got rid of the heap cache, so doesn't that make getDegree() stop running in constant time? Also: the [getDegree(RelationshipType)](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html#getDegree(org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType)) JavaDoc does not claim O(1) performance, so perhaps this whole point is moot?

Comment: I think `RETURN COUNT((u)<-[:SUBSCRIBED]-());` should be `RETURN SIZE((u)<-[:SUBSCRIBED]-());` no? I don't think COUNT will use getDegree.

Comment: @NicoleWhite: Does [getDegree(RelationshipType)](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html#getDegree(org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType)) have O(1) performance in 2.3+? Only the `getDegree()` variant without any parameters claims to be O(1) in the JavaDoc.

Comment: AFAIK it's O(1) if you leave off the other label *and* it's a dense node such that it's cached. Try it with PROFILE.
`SIZE(()-[:SUBSCRIBED]->(u))` => `GetDegree(u,Some(SUBSCRIBED)
,INCOMING)` and `SIZE((:User)-[:SUBSCRIBED]->(u))` => `length(NestedPipeExpression(
ExpandIntoPipe(
NodeByLabelScanPipe(...`

Comment: But as a general comment, the practice of storing these counts as properties has been made obsolete by SIZE.

Comment: @cybersam the rel counts are part of the rel-group-store record, per type and per direction. it remains O(1) if you specify the rel type at least for dense nodes (eg. > 50)

Comment: @cybersam a few notes. option 2(a) won't work in concurrent request scenario. you have to acquire write lock first. otherwise counter would  be inconsistent. that was my original question about. how performance will be affected in high read/write environment. ```SIZE(()-[:SUBSCRIBED]->(u))``` is O(1) unless you need to filter relationship by properties or use label. i.e. ```SIZE(()-[:SUBSCRIBED {prop:val}]->(u))``` or ```SIZE((:label)-[:SUBSCRIBED]->(u))```

Comment: @drgraduss For option 2(a), the [default locking behavior](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-locking.html) should automatically put a write lock on the `u` node when the relationship is created; so, concurrency should not be a problem.

Comment: @cybersam my bad. you're right. there is no need for explicit locking as write locks acquired on both nodes during relation creation. sorry.

Comment: Also a subscription-count that is slightly off for a while is not really critical in most applications as it is an informative number anyway.